# Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects error with if statement - Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm attempting to run an if statement to match the country of origin of marathon winners to theirs countrie's gdp data. I am getting the error 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'.

```
if df['Winner Country'] ==  gdp_data['Country']:

    if df['YEAR'] == 1970 :

        df['gdp'] = gdp_data['1970 gdp/cap']
```

gdp_data example:

```
Country 1970 gdp/cap    
Kenya   98
```

df example:

```
YEAR    Winner_Name Winner_Country  Time    Gender  
1977    Dan Cloeter USA             2:17:52 M
```

I intend to assign a gdp value to df based off both country and year(I only included partial data, there are extra columns for each year in the gdp_data datarame).

If I opt to merge I run into this issue:

data example:

```
YEAR    Winner_Name    Winner_Country   Time    Gender  Marathon_City   Country 1970    1971     
1977    Dan Cloeter    USA              2:17:52 M       Chicago         USA     5247.0  5687.0  
1978    Mark Stanforth USA              2:19:20 M       Chicago         USA     5247.0  5687.0
```

as seen the number 1970 is a variable but is also a possible result for year. How can I create a gdp variable based the year the race occurred?

What I initially tried:

```
YEAR = df_gdp['YEAR']
df_gdp['gdp'] = df[YEAR]
```

resulting in this error

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986,\n            ...\n            2009, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],\n           dtype='int64', length=258)] are in the [columns]"

a simplified example of desired results

Take this example data set

```
letter a b c d
a      1 3 4 2  
b      4 3 2 1 
c      2 1 4 3
d      3 4 2 1
```

desired results

```
letter a b c d  correct answer
a      1 3 4 2  1  
b      4 3 2 1  3 
c      2 1 4 3  4
d      3 4 2 1  1
```

how to create the 'correct answer' column?

Comment: `df['Winner_Country'] ==  gdp_data['Country']` will return a pandas `Series` of `True` and `False` values, so you wouldn't do this iteratively. Can you give more of an explanation of what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to join DataFrames on their country?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking but i think you are trying to create a gdp column that matches with the year column.

If that is the case i think this should work.

```
df_gdp['gdp'] = df_gdp.apply(lambda x: x.loc[(x['YEAR'])], axis=1)
```

Here is how i tested it.

```
##create test data
import numpy as np
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000,10000,(20,20)),columns = np.arange(1970,1990))
test['YEAR'] = np.arange(1970,1990)
test['gdp'] = test.apply(lambda x: x.loc[(x['YEAR'])],axis=1)
print(test[[1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,'YEAR','gdp']].head())

   1970  1971  1972  1973  1974  YEAR   gdp
0  4436  1288  5956  5861  2361  1970  4436
1  8918  5311  9889  2356  4646  1971  5311
2  1129  2582  6304  8488  3783  1972  6304
3  3767  8178  3947  3098  9508  1973  3098
4  7710  7713  5186  3894  9692  1974  9692
```

Comment: Yup, that is exactly what I am going for. Unfortunately when I run that code I am getting this error "IndexError: ('index out of bounds', 'occurred at index 0')".

Comment: Are there null values in some the year columns?  I am on mobile right now so i can't test the code.

Comment: No there shouldn't be, I dropped all n/a's anyway

Comment: @lynch1234 See edit using .loc allows you to do it a similar way that i had before.